# Ember JS queryRecord not triggering error state when record not found

Tags: ember.js

I have a model hook on a route that ends by returning a Promise like:

```
return route.store.queryRecord(model, {username: params.username});
```

This works great except it doesn't trigger the "error" action that is anywhere in the chain.  It is getting a 404 and logging the error in  the console.

If I change the call to "find" with a id that doesn't exist it throws the same 404, but calls the transition to the error state.  I cannot use the find for several reasons.  Am I missing something simple?

Using ember 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `queryRecord` does not catch errors that are raised in the promise as we can see here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.5.3/addon/-private/system/store/finders.js#L194

What you can do in this case is to encapsulate the call to store.query in a Promise that you would return in your routes model hook, analyze the result of store.query and reject the encapsulating Promise if you get a 404.

Comment: Wonder if they would want that functionality.  Might open a issue with the ember data.